# Problem with CORS, not allowing communication

Tags: python, cors, pythonanywhere

CORS not allowing communication. Headers not found

Using Python 3.7 and the webapp is hosted in pythonanywhere.com

This is how I'm calling CORS in my code:

```
  from flask_cors import CORS
  app = Flask(__name__)
  CORS(app)
  @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   ....
   ....
```

The Error I'm getting is this:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https‍://user.pythonanywhere.com/' from origin 'http‍://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Please assist. Don't know what I am missing or where. It says header is missing. How do I add it to allow communication? Where do I add it?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it 4xx or 5xx error rather a 200 OK success message?

Answer (score 1):

Let the CORS for all the resources in the app.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Also, please make sure you don't have any other CORS browser extension that is doing the hampering the module you have in the program.